# pChart variables in arrays

Tags: php, arrays, themes, var, pchart

I am just editing the Naked example of pChart, I have setup all of my MySQL information to retrive the AddPoints from the database.

This uses something like the below.

```
$DataSet->AddPoint(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
```

When I attempt to do

```
$var = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
$DataSet->AddPoint($var);
```

It doesn't work, but when I do

```
$var = array('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9');
$DataSet->AddPoint($var);
```

it does work.

I have also tried:

```
$var2 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,90";
$var = array("$var2");
$DataSet = new pData;
$DataSet->AddPoint($var);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, the screen gets spammed with "cannot divide by 0".

Comment: Would you mind to write full source of page ? or put somewhere and give link ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple you must provide array to this method:

```
$DataSet->AddPoint()
```

I am not sure why you are not giving array but if you want to give a string seperated by comma. You could do this way:

```
 $DataSet->AddPoint(explode(',', '1,2,3,4,5,6,90'));
```

Comment: I'm gathering the data from a MySQL database, so I plan to put it in a loop and make it get the information from $var = $rowname and then replace the $var in the addpoints with the $var, I have read the pChart MySQL documentation but it doesn't suit what I need.